# JSP Cast request.getParameter to Entity

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

This is the scenario

This is the JSP from where I get to the servlet. There is an entity called `CurrentUser` wich holds multiple fields of information about the user. I want to pass the servlet all the information about the user in a form of entity.

```
<a href="Controller?action=profile&entity=<%=_currentUser%>"> Information about the current user, like: name, id, profile picture etc... </a>
```

Inside the servlet:

```
if(request.getParameter("action").equals("profile")){
        CurrentUser _currentUser= (CurrentUser) request.getParameter("entity");
}
```

If I do a system.out to see whats inside "entity" parameter i get something like: `Package.CurrentUser@abc1235` ... and I cannot cast that, to receive it as an Entity.

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to CurrentUser
```

Is there any way to get that refference and the info inside those fields?

Comment: I meant you to use `Session` there, not request, sorry. Since, clicking on the link would make a new request, any attributes saved there, will be lost. And, the reason query parameters don't work is because only string representations can be passed using a get/post parameter. The entity object (that actually lives on the server the whole time) cannot be serialized and passed to the JSP and then back through a GET request correctly.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal still, cant you send a "memory location" into a string form, then get the object from that location and cast it as a Class ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. Say, you're somehow able to inspect the heap memory (with a debugger or some JVM tool) and you know that an object lives at "0xS0M3" address; there's nothing in Java that let's you recreate a reference to that same address so you can start using that same object again. Unlike C/C++, Java does not let you interact with the memory yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the JSP, store your `_currentUser` entity to the `Session` as

```
<% session.setAttribute("entity", _currentUser); %>
<a href="Controller?action=profile">Information ... </a>
```

Now, inside the `Controller` Servlet you can retrieve this `entity` as

```
if(request.getParameter("action").equals("profile")){
    CurrentUser _currentUser= (CurrentUser) session.getAttribute("entity");
}
```

Note, that storing the current user object into `Session` should ideally be done by the `Servlet` that forwarded the request to the JSP first. Use of Java code *scriptlets* `<% %>` inside a JSP is deprecated as JSPs should mostly be used for presentation purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't do it. Using the reference string representation you can't retrieve object instance. But you can use String object's ID parameter in the query string. Then retrieve the object by ID.

```jsp
<a href="Controller?action=profile&entity=<%=_currentUser.id%>"> Information about the current user, like: name, id, profile picture etc... </a>
```

```java
String id = request.getParameter("entity");
```

Comment: yea, thats what i was thinking from the start but I dont wanna use the database for something that already exists, i mean, why to use a query again if objects are already loaded... Is there any workaround of this?

Comment: I don't understand loaded where?

Comment: i mean, this Entity is the result of a previous result of a Select * from ... of a database. I woudnt like to charge the database with useless queries since i have the entities loaded already, instead of chargin the database i want to pass the entities around with methods from jsp to servlets. I understand request.getSession().getAttribute("entity"); I get i can apply cast on this, why not on getParameter... :P

Comment: I didn't tell you how would you retrieve the object.

Comment: having an memory refference, cant you access the data inside it...?

Comment: No, you can't. What do you mean a memory reference?